# Permutation Parser to vector<bool>, via matches

Tags: c++, boost-spirit, boost-spirit-qi

I have the following rule, inside my boost::spirit grammar;

```
rule = (qi::token(ABSTRACT) ^ qi::token(STATIC) ^ qi::token(FINAL))
```

This construct has the type of;

```
boost::fusion::vector3<boost::optional<boost::iterator_range<std::string::iterator>>, boost::optional<boost::iterator_range<std::string::iterator>>, boost::optional<boost::iterator_range<std::string::iterator>>>
```

However, what I would rather have is;

```
boost::fusion::vector3<bool, bool, bool>
```

Where each `bool` have the value of the corresponding `boost::optional<...> operator bool() const`, with a single case, I'd use `qi::matches`, as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18705954/boostoptional-to-bool-inside-boostspiritqi-grammar/). However applying this approach yields;

```
(qi::matches[qi::raw_token(ABSTRACT)] ^ qi::matches[qi::raw_token(STATIC)] ^ qi::matches[qi::raw_token(FINAL)])
```

Which has the type;

```
boost::fusion::vector3<boost::optional<bool>, boost::optional<bool>, boost::optional<bool>>
```

Which is indeed not what I wanted, so how would I go about, matching these three tokens in random order, and getting whether they were matched as booleans?

Comment: @P0W This is a boost fusion vector, not a `std::vector` which is the one on which you wish to avoid bools.

Comment: I guess some context is missing?

Comment: The attribute of the permutation parser will always be `fusion::vector<boost::optional<Whatever>...>`. I think that this vector should be "compatible" with a `fusion::vector<Whatever...>` (it should assign every optional that is not empty to the corresponding element). The problem I see with your code is that `qi::matches` always succeeds and because of that I think that your code will only work when all three keywords are present and in the correct order.

Comment: Correction to the comment above: it works as long as `final` does not precede any of the others or `static` is not found before `abstract` (Sorry I can't express this better in English). I think that if you initialize your fusion vector to false,false,false and use `qi::raw_token(KEYWORD) >> qi::attr(true)` as the arguments of the permutation, it should work.

Comment: I see you're moving in the direction that I'd personally take with the class modifiers :) This is good news. I think I can spare a while now to see whether I can "simplify" your grammar into something devirtualized and semantic-action-free

Comment: @sehe: I'm still far from done, if it's the repository your browsing :), still need to handle expressions and a few special case statements. - And of course debugging.

Comment: @Skeen I know, I'm just trying to see if I can give you an "artist's impression"

Comment: @Skeen note that in my 'artist impression' (https://bitbucket.org/sehe/joos2compiler-refactor) I show [another _approach_ here using `phoenix::at_c<>` in the semantic action](https://bitbucket.org/sehe/joos2compiler-refactor/src/8c6d10677aaf1323ce0f23195b9a939d8b8088ca/src/Parser.hpp?at=default#cl-141).

Comment: @sehe It would be ... customary to post that as an answer ;)

Comment: @cv_and_he lol, touché! _(It's posted as a part of [this general answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18731900/85371), though; dunno if it counts?)_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming that you don't really need a `fusion::vector<bool,bool,bool>` and you just want it to work. If this assumption is wrong simply say something in the comments.

As you can see in the [documentation](http://www.boost.org/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/qi/reference/operator/permutation.html#spirit.qi.reference.operator.permutation.attributes) the attribute of the permutation parser is `tuple<optional<A>,optional<B>>`. In your case this translates to `fusion::vector<optional<bool>,optional<bool>,optional<bool>>`. Thanks to the way Spirit works with attributes this vector is compatible with a simple `fusion::vector<bool,bool,bool>`. In this case this means that every non-empty component of the optional vector (the ones that are actually matched by the permutation parser) is assigned to its corresponding one of the plain bool vector, and the rest of the components in this latter vector remain unchanged.

The problem I see in you example is in the way the [`qi::matches` directive](http://www.boost.org/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/qi/reference/directive/matches.html#spirit.qi.reference.directive.matches.expression_semantics)(it always succeeds) and the permutation parser(each element in the permutation set may occur at most once) work. You can see this problem in the output of the program below:

```
USING MATCHES: final abstract static

<abstract1>

  <try>final abstract stati</try>

  <success>final abstract stati</success>

  <attributes>[0]</attributes>

</abstract1>

<static1>

  <try>final abstract stati</try>

  <success>final abstract stati</success>

  <attributes>[0]</attributes>

</static1>

<final1>

  <try>final abstract stati</try>

  <success> abstract static</success>

  <attributes>[1]</attributes>

</final1>
```

The first rule it tries is `abstract1`, since the input at that point is "final", the argument of `qi::matches` fails and thus `qi::matches` succeeds returning false. Since `abstract1` has already succeeded, the permutation parser will never try it again. Next `static1` is tried, with the exact same result. After that the input is still "final" and the rule tried is `final1`, it succeeds returning true. All three arguments have succeeded, and so the permutation parser ends, leaving "abstract static" unparsed.

One way to do what you want is using something similar to the second option sehe recommends in his answer. You'll need to use `(qi::raw_token(ABSTRACT) >> qi::attr(true)) ^ (qi::raw_token(STATIC) >> qi::attr(true)) ^ (qi::raw_token(FINAL) >> qi::attr(true))`. `KEYWORD >> qi::attr(true)` will succeed returning true when `KEYWORD` matches, and fail otherwise. As mentioned earlier the components of the final vector that correspond with empty optionals remain unchanged so you need to make sure that they are initialized to false (using a default constructor for example).

[Running on Coliru:](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/63ffdd920c3317f8)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

#define BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG

#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <boost/fusion/include/adapt_struct.hpp>

struct class_info
{
    class_info():abstract_(),static_(),final_(){}
    bool abstract_;
    bool static_;
    bool final_;
};

BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT
(
    class_info,
    (bool, abstract_)
    (bool, static_)
    (bool, final_)
)

namespace qi=boost::spirit::qi;

template <typename Parser>
void parse_triplet(const std::string& test, const Parser& parser)
{
    std::string::const_iterator iter=test.begin(), end=test.end();
    class_info parsed_class;

    bool result=qi::phrase_parse(iter,end,parser,qi::space,parsed_class);

    if(!result)
    {
        std::cout << "The triplet could not be parsed. Unparsed: " << std::string(iter,end) << std::endl;
    }
    else
    {
        if(iter==end)
        {
            std::cout << "A triplet was parsed." << std::endl;
            std::cout << parsed_class.abstract_ << parsed_class.static_ << parsed_class.final_ << std::endl;
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << "A triplet was parsed, but part of the input remained unparsed." << std::endl;
            std::cout << parsed_class.abstract_ << parsed_class.static_ << parsed_class.final_ << std::endl;
            std::cout << "Unparsed: " << std::string(iter,end) << std::endl;
        }
    }

}


int main()
{
    std::vector<std::string> tests;
    tests.push_back("final abstract static");
    tests.push_back("final abstract");
    tests.push_back("static");
    tests.push_back("static abstract");
    qi::rule<std::string::const_iterator,bool(),qi::space_type> abstract1, abstract2, static1, static2, final1, final2;
    abstract1 = qi::matches[qi::lit("abstract")];
    abstract2 = qi::lit("abstract") >> qi::attr(true);
    static1 = qi::matches[qi::lit("static")];
    static2 = qi::lit("static") >> qi::attr(true);
    final1 = qi::matches[qi::lit("final")];
    final2 = qi::lit("final") >> qi::attr(true);

    BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG_NODES( (abstract1)(abstract2)(static1)(static2)(final1)(final2) );

    for(std::size_t cont=0; cont < tests.size(); ++cont)
    {
            //THIS IS WRONG
        std::cout << "USING MATCHES: " << tests[cont] << std::endl;
        parse_triplet(tests[cont],abstract1 ^ static1 ^ final1);

            //THIS WORKS
        std::cout << "USING EXPLICIT ATTRIBUTE: " << tests[cont] << std::endl;
        parse_triplet(tests[cont],abstract2 ^ static2 ^ final2);


    }
}
```

Comment: I went with something along the lines of the explicit attribute approach.